# SELECT column name starting with numeral

Tags: sql, database-design

This one is out of morbid curiosity. I have a *very* badly named table here:

```sql
CREATE TABLE badtable (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    "customer name" VARCHAR(63),
    "order" VARCHAR(12),
    "1st" date,
    "last-date" date
);
```

I am trying to show when you might desperately need delimited column names. However, the following is not an error:

```sql
SELECT
    "customer name",
    "order",
    1st,    --  no delimiter
    "last-date"
FROM badtable;
```

Instead it happily gives me a column called `st`.

This works on both PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQL Server, so it’s not limited to a quirk of one of them.

How is the `1st` column name being interpreted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some situations whitespace is not required as long as the DBMS is able to read the expression unambiguously.

```
select 1st
```

selects a 1. What follows is the alias name. Hence the same as

```
select 1 st
```

or

```
select 1 as st
```

Comment: I have always considered the optional `AS` as a bad idea, as it can lead to so many ambiguities. Thanks for clearing that up.